# Average Matrices with missing data using R

Tags: r, matrix, command, average, na

I have three 108x108 matrices, from which I want to calculate their average matrix. There is missing data in the matrices, which I want to be excluded from the calculation of the cell average. If there are only two date entries in the three matrices, the mean of the two existing entries should be computed for that cell. An illustration follows below. There must be a command to easily average matrices with NA?

```
Matrix 1: 

3  3  3

NA 3  3

Matrix 2: 

3  3  3

3  3  3

Matrix 3: 

3  3  3

3  3  3

Average Matrix:

3  3  3

3  3  3
```

"Average <- (a + b + c)/3" won't work because of the missing data entries.
"mean" appears not suitable to average matrices.

Hope somebody can guide the way! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three base solutions:

**1)** Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use `mapply` and then reshape the result back to a matrix.

```
Mean <- function(...) mean(c(...), na.rm = TRUE)
replace(m1, TRUE, mapply(Mean, m1, m2, m3))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    3    3    3
## [2,]    3    3    3
```

**2)** Use sapply to create a matrix with one column per input matrix and then average the rows giving a vector.  Reshape that back to a matrix.

```
L <- list(m1, m2, m3)
replace(L[[1]], TRUE, rowMeans(sapply(L, c), na.rm = TRUE))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    3    3    3
## [2,]    3    3    3
```

**3)** Replace NA with 0 and sum and then divide by the number of non-NAs.  We could alternately use zoo's na.fill(x, 0) to replace NA's in x with 0 in place of na2zero.

```
na2zero <- function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)
Sum <- function(L, f) Reduce("+", lapply(L, f))
Sum(L, na2zero) / Sum(L, Negate(is.na))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    3    3    3
## [2,]    3    3    3
```

**3a)** or write it out instead of using Reduce:

```
(na2zero(m1) + na2zero(m2) + na2zero(m3)) /
   ((!is.na(m1)) + (!is.na(m2)) + (!is.na(m3)))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    3    3    3
## [2,]    3    3    3
```

### Note

```
m1 <- m2 <- m3 <- matrix(3, 2, 3)
m1[2, 1] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# create sample data reproducibly
m1 = m2 = m3 = matrix(3, 2, 3)
m1[2, 1] = NA

# put your matrices in an array
a = array(c(m1, m2, m3), dim = c(dim(m1), 3))

# apply the `mean` function with `na.rm = TRUE`
apply(a, 1:2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    3    3
# [2,]    3    3    3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `BaseR`,

```
matrix(rowMeans(matrix(rbind(m,k,l),ncol=3),na.rm=T),2)
```

gives,

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3
```

**Data:**

```
m <- matrix(3,2,3)
k <-  matrix(3,2,3)
l <-  matrix(3,2,3)
m[2,1] <- NA
```